# Get <script> Tag, without contains multiple words

Tags: regex, whitelist

I want to get all  Tags, that not contains multiple words (domains). Here is my code:

```
document\.write\(.*<(script|scr\'\+\'ipt|scr\"\+\"ipt)(?!(google-analytics\.com|domain\.com).*)>.*\)
```

What i want: all Tags wihout "google-analytics.com" AND "domain.com"

Can anybody help?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: [Obligatory answer for everyone wanting to parse HTML with regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1620671)

Comment: Upvoted previous comment, but here its more a grep on specific tags, so should be handlable with a regex. For the OP: some kind of source exemple ? you may try it on http://regex101.com to see what match or not. Side note: I don't understand the reason to be of your first ored regex, for the quotes between script, I need to see a use case to understand why you did that I think...

Comment: @Philipp Yep, i often hear that. I want to try it with xpath too

Comment: My problem with xpath is, that i must find these codes: <script>, <scr'+'ipt>, <scr"+"ipt>. And that code is within a document.write()

Answer (score 0):

As Philipp says, its not a good way to solve my problem. I've solved it with xpath.